# Evaluate $\int_{|z|=3} \frac{cos(\pi z)}{(z-2)^2(z+5)(z+1)} \ dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

> I am trying to solve $$I=\int_{|z|=3} \frac{cos(\pi z)}{(z-2)^2(z+5)(z+1)} \ dz.$$

My attempt:

*Residue Theorem:*

Let $$f(z)=\frac{cos(\pi z)}{(z-2)^2(z+5)(z+1)}.$$
Now, $$\text{Res}(f,2)=\lim_{z\to 2} \frac{d}{dz} \left(\frac{cos\pi z}{(z+5)(z+1)}\right)=-\frac{10}{441}.$$
$$\text{Res}(f,-1)=\lim_{z\to -1} \left(\frac{cos\pi z}{(z-2)^2(z+5)}\right)=-\frac{1}{36}.$$
Hence, by the Residue Theorem
$$I=2\pi i\left(-\frac{10}{441}-\frac{1}{36}\right)=\pi i\left(-\frac{89}{882}\right).$$

Cauchy's Integral Formula:

Let $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ be a small non-intersecting circles around $z=-1$ and $z=2$ respectively. 
\begin{align}
I&=\int_{\Gamma_1} \frac{\frac{\cos(\pi z)}{(z-2)^2(z+5)}}{(z+1)} \ dz +\int_{\Gamma_2} \frac{\frac{\cos(\pi z)}{(z+1)(z+5)}}{(z-2)^2} \ dz \\
&=2\pi i \left(\frac{\cos(\pi z)}{(z-2)^2(z+5)}\right)_{z=-1}+2\pi i \frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{\cos(\pi z)}{(z+1)(z+5)}\right)_{z=-2} \\
&=\pi i\left(-\frac{89}{882}\right)
\end{align}

Yet the answer I have is $-\frac{131}{198}\pi$. I do not see how I can be incorrect.

Comment: Where does $-\frac {131}{198} \pi$ come from?

Comment: That's the answer in the lecture slides. I think it's a terrible mistake, but I'd like to (triple) check, as it is quite a fundamental question. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You have a couple mistakes in your post indicating the poles you are evaluating, but I think that is just input error.  (check your signs above.)  Otherwise, I am not seeing anything yet.

Comment: Thanks, I spotted some silly typos. I derived the answer via two different methods, so it should be correct.

Comment: Your solution is correct to me.